# Loop in Qlikview load

Tags: for-loop, aggregation, qlikview

I have a table below and i want to aggregate the number for each day and product. So i want to get the aggregate each day by product, even when the product was not available on that day.

**Source table**

| Date | product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/01/2021 | a | 300 |
| 05/01/2021 | a | 200 |
| 04/01/2021 | a | -100 |
| 03/01/2021 | a | -500 |
| 02/01/2021 | a | 200 |
| 01/01/2021 | a | 100 |
| 05/01/2021 | b | 500 |
| 03/01/2021 | b | -900 |
| 02/01/2021 | b | 500 |
| 02/01/2021 | c | 250 |

**Expected outcome**
|Report Date|product|Amount
|-------------|-----------|-----------
|06/01/2021|a|200
|06/01/2021|b|100
|06/01/2021|c|250
|05/01/2021|a|-100
|05/01/2021|b|100
|05/01/2021|c|250
|04/01/2021|a|-300
|04/01/2021|b|-400
|04/01/2021|c|250
|03/01/2021|a|-200
|03/01/2021|b|-400
|03/01/2021|c|250
|02/01/2021|a|300
|02/01/2021|b|500
|02/01/2021|c|250
|01/01/2021|a|100

Please let me know if this is possible

Comment: It is possible in a few ways. Do you want to do it in a table in the front end?

Comment: No, i want to do it in the load script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script method:
I added a return for product a on the 6th to show why I added the group by.

```
RAW:
load * inline [
  Date,     Product,    Amount
  06/01/2021,   a,  300
  06/01/2021,   a,  -100
  05/01/2021,   a,  200
  04/01/2021,   a,  -100
  03/01/2021,   a,  -500
  02/01/2021,   a,  200
  01/01/2021,   a,  100
  05/01/2021,   b,  500
  03/01/2021,   b,  -900
  02/01/2021,   b,  500
  02/01/2021,   c,  250
  ];

SALES:
load distinct 
  Date
resident RAW;

left join
load Distinct
  Product 
Resident RAW;

left join
load
  Date,
  Product,
  sum(Amount) as Amount
resident RAW
group by
  Date,
  Product; drop table RAW;

SALES_FIN:
NoConcatenate
load 
  Date,
  Product,
  if(isnull(Amount),0,Amount) as Amount
Resident SALES; drop table SALES;
```